# changing charger port on laptop

Tags: power-supply, laptop-repair, charging

Is it hard to change the charging port on my Acer laptop or do I have to take it to the repair shop? Is there any way to charge it without fixing that port? I only need to charge it long enough to remove my files and pics.

Comment: Probably easier to just remove the hard drive and use a second system, hard drive dock, etc, to copy the data off of it

Comment: If you provide the model of your laptop, we may be able to provide more details.

Answer (score 2):

It depends entirely on the model of the laptop.

If it's a surface mount jack, replacing it will be difficult and require soldering.  In these situations, there's a good chance the board it's soldered to has been broken as well.

If you're lucky, the jack will be connected by another internal plug (like the one seen below).  In this situation, you can just replace it with one specifically for the model of your laptop (eBay tends to be a good source for these).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Opening a laptop is a pain, too many tiny screws in almost-hidden places. Plus the flat cables. And the plastic latches that easily break.

After you open it… What are you going to do? What exactly are you going to replace? The components in a laptop are so tightly integrated that it becomes near-impossible to replace most of them.

In addition, how are you sure it is just the charger port? Could it be the charger circuitry? Do you have enough Electronics knowledge to test this stuff and replace the components?

In my humble opinion, it is probably not worth the trouble. Even more so because you just want to get the files out of the laptop. If that's what you want, just remove the hard drive and plug it in another machine.

If you want to learn more about the internals of a laptop (or any gadget), I can recommend this site: https://www.ifixit.com/Device/Acer_Laptop (no, I am not affiliated to them)